# Referring to dynamically determined class variables (self.[name])

Tags: python, tkinter

new to python and have been googling around. Am trying out python class with a simple calculator.

Am currently using tkinter.

```
        self.grid()
        self.customfont = font.Font(family="Arial", size=14)
        self.entryVariable=tkinter.StringVar()           

        dictFields = {"S0":"Enter initial price, S0, here.",
                      "K":"Enter strike price, K, here.",
                      "T":"Enter time to maturity, T, here.",
                      "r":"Enter risk-free rate, r, here.",
                      "sigma":"Enter volatility, sigma, here.",
                      "q":"Enter dividend yield, q, here."
                      }
        i = 2
        for key in dictFields.keys():
            self.entryVariable = tkinter.StringVar()

            ## Unsure of this but I googled that I can create dynamically named class variables on the fly in this manner - would like to check if this is correct and if it is the best way to do it?
            setattr(self, key, 0) 

            ## another difficulty is that subsequently i have to set the properties of this variables - self.key seems to return be the literal self.key rather than self.S0, self.K etc.  
            self.key = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariable, justify="center") 
            self.key.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky="EW")
            self.key.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
            self.entryVariable.set(dictFields[key])
            i+=2
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
I am unsure if the downs are because my questions wasn't clear (as they are embedded within comments in the code) or if the question itself is generally a bad one. Would appreciate if someone could kindly advise.

Questions:
How can I create class variables dynamically? I have googled a few methods that involved `setattr(self, key, 0)` or `"{0}".format(key)`. However, I cant seem to get them to work as I am trying to assign a tkinter.Entry object to this dynamically created class variable name.

Thanks again.

Comment: And what is your question about instance variables?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 hey thanks for the response! self.key seems to create a class variable "self.key" rather than self.S0 etc. With reference to Back2Basics, does that mean if i have already passed self to init. 
"key =..." is equivalent to "S0=...", "K=..." etc? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`self` is great, if you are in something that can call itself a `self`.

For this you will need a class so you can put these variables in one place and make sense of this thing you are building.

how about:

```
class calculator(<you_might_need_another_class_here>):
   """ just a normal calculator """
```

Then your next line would define how you want to start the calculator

```
def __init__(self): #here is where self shows up
    pass
    #replace "pass" with anything calculators do automatically
```

After this point your use of `self` will work inside this class.

yes you can dynamically create attributes with setattr.  Make sure all your keys are strings.

But the last question is No.  You are accessing "self.key" instead of self.S0
so a line like

```
self.key = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariable, justify="center")
```

can become

```
setattr(self,key,tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariable, justify="center")
```

but quite honestly I don't know what to do with this line.

```
self.key.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky="EW")
```

you can use getattr(self,key) instead to pull the dynamically created self.keys

Comment: I don't think that actually addresses the question. It looks like the issue has something to do with `setattr(self, key, 0)`, though.

Comment: I'm getting around to it.

Comment: Hey @Back2Basics, thanks too for replying! does that mean if i have already passed self to init. "key =..." is equivalent to "S0=...", "K=..." etc? Thank you! (as per above)

Comment: If you don't have an answer to the question, please don't post filler while you write it up.

Comment: Answers are always in flux here.  They can change years later.  But I really thought the point of the question was in the Heading or the text and not the comments in the code.

Comment: @Back2Basics...any idea on how that can be done? Thanks!